# Microsoft SQL SSDT - Test Project - Mocks and Constraints for Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SSDT with units tests(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851200(v=vs.103).aspx) and I can't find a way to set up the parameters for stored procedures outside the resx file, in a C# file that everybody could acess.

Is there a way to that?

An example:

```
-- database unit test for dbo.InsertFuncionario
DECLARE @RC AS INT, @ID AS INT, @SedeID AS SMALLINT, @nome AS VARCHAR (200), @cpf AS VARCHAR (11), @PISPASEP AS VARCHAR (11), @certificadoReservista AS VARCHAR (20), @cargoID AS SMALLINT, @dataNascimento AS SMALLDATETIME, @dataAdmissao AS SMALLDATETIME, @horarioTrabalho AS VARCHAR (100), @grauInstrucaoID AS SMALLINT, @folgaSemanal AS VARCHAR (100), @salario AS MONEY, @autorizadoPor AS VARCHAR (200), @estadoCivil AS VARCHAR (20), @dataDemissao AS SMALLDATETIME, @nomeImagem AS VARCHAR (200), @codigoANAC AS VARCHAR (20), @foto AS VARCHAR (MAX), @licenca AS VARCHAR (20);

SELECT @RC = 0,
       @SedeID = 1,
       @nome = 'CANINDE SISTEMAS PARA AVIACAO',
       @cpf = '07996501610',
       @PISPASEP = NULL,
       @certificadoReservista = NULL,
       @cargoID = 1,
       @dataNascimento = '19871127',
       @dataAdmissao = getdate(),
       @horarioTrabalho = NULL,
       @grauInstrucaoID = 6,
       @folgaSemanal = NULL,
       @salario = NULL,
       @autorizadoPor = NULL,
       @estadoCivil = NULL,
       @dataDemissao = NULL,
       @nomeImagem = NULL,
       @codigoANAC = NULL,
       @foto = NULL,
       @licenca = NULL;

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[InsertFuncionario] @ID OUTPUT, @SedeID, @nome, @cpf, @PISPASEP, @certificadoReservista, @cargoID, @dataNascimento, @dataAdmissao, @horarioTrabalho, @grauInstrucaoID, @folgaSemanal, @salario, @autorizadoPor, @estadoCivil, @dataDemissao, @nomeImagem, @codigoANAC, @foto, @licenca;

SELECT @RC AS RC,
       @ID AS ID;
```

Right now, the solution that I thought, is to inicialize an key-value table for my tests, and do an select every time that I want an value.

The value for the @nome will be inside a table and I will do in a pre-test an insert on it. an I will change the resx querie, to do a select and retrieve the value.

Comment: It is not really answer to your question, but I suggest to use tSQLt unit tests instead of Microsoft ones...